# Difference between the AdornerLayer.Update methods

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

What exactly are the differences between [AdornerLayer.Update()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer.update?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Documents_AdornerLayer_Update) and [AdornerLayer.Update(UIElement)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer.update?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Documents_AdornerLayer_Update_System_Windows_UIElement_)?

As far as I understand it, there is exactly one adorner layer per ui element, which you can get with [AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(Visual)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer.getadornerlayer?view=netcore-3.1). The only difference I can see is if there isn't a adorner layer for each ui element. So for example if I have the following visual tree:

```
UIElement1  
-> UIElement2  
-> UIElement3
```

Then somehow `UIElement2` and `3` don't have their own adorner layer but use the adorner layer of `UIElement1`. And then `Update()` would update all adorners for `UIElement1`, `2` and `3` and `Update(UIElement)` would only update the adorners for the corresponding ui element.

So what are the conditions for when a UI element has its own adorner layer and when it uses the adorner layer of a UI element higher up in the visual tree?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you are making a custom [adorner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/adorners-overview), then you just have to override `OnRender`.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm trying to understand the difference in the Update methods to improve the performance of my adorners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `UIElement` does *not* automatically have its own, unique `AdornerLayer`. Take a look at this documentation:

[Adorners Overview - Adorning a Single UIElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/adorners-overview#adorning-a-single-uielement)

> GetAdornerLayer walks up the visual tree, starting at the specified UIElement, and returns the first adorner layer it finds. (If no adorner layers are found, the method returns `null`.)

[AdornerDecorator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.adornerdecorator)

> The AdornerDecorator specifies the position of the AdornerLayer in the
>   visual tree. It is typically used in a ControlTemplate for a control
>   that might host Adorner objects. For example, the ControlTemplate of a
>   Window contains an AdornerDecorator so that the child elements of the
>   window can be adorned. The GetAdornerLayer method returns `null` if you
>   pass in an element that does not have an AdornerDecorator as an
>   ancestor in its visual tree.

So, if you use a `Window` as the root element, there is guaranteed to be at least one `Adorner` in the visual tree, there may be more depending on what other elements you use.

Comment: Interesting, so I could add my own AdornerLayer if necessary  by creating a custom ControlTemplate. Is there a list of what controls already provide a AdornerLayer or do I need to inspect each ControlTemplate?

Comment: @gartenriese I don't know of any list. But you shouldn't really need to know. As far as I can tell, `Adorner`s work the same regardless of how many `AdornerLayer`s there are- as long as there is at least one.

Comment: I have lots of adorners, so I'm worried about performance. I'm looking for ways to update some adorners without updating all the other adorners.

Comment: @gartenriese You could try calling `InvalidateVisual` on individual `Adorner`s.